# Why Query Not useing index here

Tags: mysql, indexing

my query

```
      SELECT Info.InfoID,
      SessionInfo.SessionInfoID,
      SessionInfo.ANI,
      ANumber.ANumber,
      tmfInfo.PTime,
      tmfInfo.PTry,
      SessionInfo.CardID,
      tmfInfo.Status
 FROM tmfInfo,
      SessionInfo,
      ANumber ,
      ANumberLog,
      ANumberGroup,
      ANumberGroupLog
WHERE (tmfInfo.IVRSessionInfoID = SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID)
  AND (SessionInfo.ANumberLogID = ANumber.ANumberLogID)
  AND (ANumber.AccessNumberLogID = ANumberLog.ANumberLogID)
  AND (ANumberrLog.ANumberGroupID = ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupID)
  AND (ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupLogID = ANumberGroupLog.ANumberGroupLogID)
  AND (SessionInfo.SessionCallTime >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00'
  AND (SessionInfo.SessionCallTime <= '2013-08-01 23:59:59')
  AND (ANumberLog.IsDeleted = '0')
  AND (ANumberLog.IsActive = '1')
  AND (ANumberGroupLog.IsDeleted = '0')
  AND (ANumberGroupLog.IsActive = '1')
 ORDER BY SessionInfo.SessionCallTime,tmfInfo.PTime DESC;
```

Explain query results

---

```
     id select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref  rows   Extra   
       1    SIMPLE  DtmfInfo    ALL SessionInfoID                 1728919   Using temporary; Using filesort 
      1 SIMPLE  SessionInfo eq_ref  PRIMARY,SessionCallTime,ANumberLogID    PRIMARY 8   IVRDtmfInfo.SessionInfoID   1   Using where 
      1 SIMPLE  Anumber ref AnumberLogID    AnumberLogID    5   SessionInfo.ANumberLogID    1   Using where 
     1  SIMPLE  AnumberLog  eq_ref  PRIMARY,AcumberGroupID,IsActive,IsDeleted   PRIMARY 4   SessionInfo.ANumberLogID    1   Using where 
      1 SIMPLE  AnumberGroup    eq_ref  PRIMARY,ANumberGroupLogID   PRIMARY 4   AnumberLog.ANumberGroupID   1       
      1 SIMPLE  AnumberGroupLog eq_ref  PRIMARY,IsActive,IsDeleted  PRIMARY 4   Using where Using where Using where
```

---

I have an index on the SessionInfoID field
query  DtmfInfo table not using index ....

Any help/explanation would be helpful. Using mysql 5.5.14

Comment: You better post this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/?as=1. Also, you need to specify where the DtmfInfo is referenced in your query?

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table used in the query

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have to use FORCE INDEX :

the query will be like this :

```
    SELECT Info.InfoID,
          SessionInfo.SessionInfoID,
          SessionInfo.ANI,
          ANumber.ANumber,
          tmfInfo.PTime,
          tmfInfo.PTry,
          SessionInfo.CardID,
          tmfInfo.Status
     FROM tmfInfo  FORCE INDEX ( index_name )   inner join  SessionInfo on  mfInfo.IVRSessionInfoID = SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID , 
          ANumber ,
          ANumberLog,
          ANumberGroup,
          ANumberGroupLog
    WHERE 
      (SessionInfo.ANumberLogID = ANumber.ANumberLogID)
      AND (ANumber.AccessNumberLogID = ANumberLog.ANumberLogID)
      AND (ANumberrLog.ANumberGroupID = ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupID)
      AND (ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupLogID = ANumberGroupLog.ANumberGroupLogID)
      AND (SessionInfo.SessionCallTime >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00'
      AND (SessionInfo.SessionCallTime
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your query, my suggestion is:

You can use ...  AND SessionInfo.SessionCallTime **BETWEEN** '2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-01 23:59:59'

I'd prefer to use JOINS for this part:
      (SessionInfo.ANumberLogID = ANumber.ANumberLogID)
      AND (ANumber.AccessNumberLogID = ANumberLog.ANumberLogID)
      AND (ANumberrLog.ANumberGroupID = ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupID)
      AND (ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupLogID = ANumberGroupLog.ANumberGroupLogID)

Modifying like this:

SELECT *
FROM  tmfInfo
INNER JOIN ANumber  USING (ANumberLogID)
INNER JOIN ANumberLog USING (ANumberLogID)
...

and of course, FORCE INDEX can reduce the time of your query. Some times, MySQL doesn't select the best INDEX.

I hope it helps!